# "cant find symbol" .length on String object

Tags: java

When I type this code in it brings up an error saying

> "cannot find symbol length"

All I am trying to do is find the length of the string and store that length into a variable.

Can anyone help me find the problem?

```
String[] words = {
    "hello", "java", "yamaha", "dell", "hydro"
};

a = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
b = (words[a]).length;
```

Comment: Looks like you will sometimes get an OOB Exception as well

Comment: As per this code `for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++ ) {
      System.out.println(x);
      int a = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
      int b = (words[a]).length ();
  }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()) class doesn't have a `length` property, you need to call `length()` method

```
 b = (words[a]).length();
       /\
       ||
       ||
       ||
     Since you are accessing the a'th index of array, which returns String hence you have to call length() method instead of length which is the field in array instead
```

As Scarywombat pointed out you might get Out Of Bounds exception as well, so you need to change your condition

```
a = (int) (Math.random() * 5); // 5 instead of 6
```

Answer (score 0):

String doesn't support length variable , length variable is used for other array , instead use length() method.

```
 String[] words =
{
    "hello", "java", "yamaha", "dell", "hydro"
};



a = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
b = (words[a]).length();
```

Comment: Is `a = (int) (Math.random() * 6);` correct?

Comment: yes.. i think there is no need to cast to int @Scary Wombet

Comment: @PrakashSharma he isn't talking about casting, you have to cast definitely. The problem is that this statement can give a index 5 which will cause out of bounds exception, Since our array's length is 5

Comment: @NeerajJain But to be fair current question is about compilation error and this post answers it. Problem shown in comments is answer for OP's next question where index will be out of bounds (sometimes). If that is the reason someone down-voted then I can't really agree with it.

Comment: @Pshemo firstly I didn't downvote. I was just helping Prakash to understand what Scary wombat is saying :)

Comment: @NeerajJain I never said you did :) Was just pointing out to others who may see that `-1` score that this down-vote may not be well deserved. Sometimes when people see negatively scored answer they thing/[act] like: "there needs to be something wrong with this answer... [read comments]... oh that is what is wrong [adds another down-vote]". I simply wanted to prevent it which is why my comment was `@linked` to yours.

Answer (score -1):

String doesn't have `length` property whereas array has it.
We need to use **`length()` for strings** and **`length` for Arrays**.